# WordPress \ Bootstrap 4 not building breadcrumbs correctly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have this code in my WordPress `functions.php` to create breadcrumbs for pages only. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

I want to use bootstrap navs. The problem is that the short tag,
the_title(), is writing the page name "Search" before the li tag, and
empty quotes within li tag.

```
function get_breadcrumb() {

    echo '<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">';
    echo '<ol class="breadcrumb">';

    if(!is_home() && !is_front_page()) {
        echo '<li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="'.home_url().'" rel="nofollow">Home</a></li>';
        if (is_page()) {
            echo '<li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">"'.the_title().'"</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ol>';
    echo '</nav>';
}
```

### Result

```
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
<ol class="breadcrumb">
<li class="breadcrumb-item">
<a href="https://example.com" rel="nofollow">Home</a></li>Search
<li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">""</li>
</ol>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

[`the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/) echoes the title, by default. Use [`get_the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/) instead.

```
function get_breadcrumb() {

    echo '<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">';
    echo '<ol class="breadcrumb">';

    if(!is_home() && !is_front_page()) {
        echo '<li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="'.home_url().'" rel="nofollow">Home</a></li>';
        if (is_page()) {
            echo '<li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">"'.get_the_title().'"</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ol>';
    echo '</nav>';
}
```